# Update Only one field in MS SQL Using Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have been banging my head with this script and need to assistance.  I am trying to create a registration form that connects to the following sql fields: `Acct_ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Confirmation`, `RegistrationDate` and `AccountNum`.

What I have been able to do so far is get the form inserted into the database and have a cdosys email sent out to the email address(username)  with a querystring attached to a link embedded in the email.  The querystring is the `AccountNum` field from the registration form.

What I want to try to do is update the confirmation field only in the database when the user clicks on the link which looks like this: 
http://www.domainname.com/Presenter_Account_Confirm_Registration.asp?AccountNum=2152012319101300766363428210152260.

I verified that the Account Number is transferred to the confirmation page, but I am stumped as to how to update just the confirmation field in the database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Update the confirmation column with what? `1`? `'True'`? The current time? Something else? What are the data types of `Confirmation` and `AccountNum` and what is the table name? Is `Acct_ID` the same as `AccountNum`? Why do you reference them with two different names?

Answer (score 2):

Making some assumptions here, that `Acct_ID` is an `INT`, is the same as `AccountNum`, and that you want to set `Confirmation` to `1`:

```
<%
  Acct_ID = Request.QueryString("AccountNum")
  set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn ' assume ADODB.Connection has been set up
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
  sql = "UPDATE dbo.tablename SET Confirmation = 1 WHERE Acct_ID = ?"
  cmd.Parameters(0).value = Acct_ID
  cmd.CommandText = sql
  cmd.Execute
%>
```